# AWS RDS different user or security group for reader and writer cluster endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I crated an Aurora MySQL cluster with reader and writer instances. I would like to restrict the access to the writer cluster endpoint so that only my application can access it. I would also like to make the reader cluster endpoint available to external applications and users. Is it possible to create a MySQL user or a security group that applies only to the writer or reader cluster endpoints?